# Math sticker meanings

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I am trying to understand what these stickers mean.
[image]

The ones on the top row are:

- Good one!
- I am impressed!
- (I know $\sum x_n /n$ is the mean of the $x_i$, but I don't understand this one)

The bottom row is:

- This improvement is a good sign
- (I know $\sin(\pi/2-\theta)=\cos\theta$, but I also don't get this one)
- Awesome work!

Comment: I think the $\cos$ in the 5th is "because".

Comment: This work is above average is the third one.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate at [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3: "This work is above average"  ($\sum{x}_n/n$ is indeed the average)

5: "Complementary - this is good work" (cosine is the complementary angle of sine)

Comment: 5 is close, but not quite right. "Complementary cos" should be read as "Complementary, 'cause". So, it should be "Complementary, 'cause this is good work!"

Comment: Good catch!  You could also read it as "A complement...this is good work!"